# How to bring text qualifier back to an exported flat file

Tags: text, ssis, delimiter, csv

We designed an SSIS package for our client to export data from their databases to flat files that need to be further processed by us.

In short, one of the flat file destination in DFT does not have `text qualifier` specified. These days we received files with lots data that has the same symbol as the column delimiter in the text. And the appearance is unpredictable, meaning it could show up in any of the column.

Before sending the updated package to the client, is there any other way (No hard coded update from the backend, such as update each column with the column from the right) to know where the original column ends between each?

The easiest way is ask them to export the files again with `Text Qualifier` to escape the symbol, but for business concern, it might not be the our top1 pick, any one experienced this before, any advices and suggestions?